# Controlling LINQ query order based on other list of integers

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a LINQ query where I select the video info from table Videos. The query selects only those videos whose IDs are present in the following list:

```
List<int> results; //Has some values
var query = from l in dataContext.Videos
                 where results.Contains(l.ID)
                 select l;
```

Now how do I order the items(Video infos) in the query such the their IDs follow the same order as the List results?

I am able to do this as:

```
List<int> results; //Has some values
var query = from k in results
            from l in dataContext.Videos
            where k==l.ID
            select l;
```

But this is slow, I need something faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `join`,  it's much faster

```
var orderedByIDList = from k in results
join l in dataContext.Videos
on k equals l.Id
select l;
```

---

Addon/Edit due to @MarcinJuraszek and @Phil comments, thanks guys.

Basically grab your data first, then sort so here's what I got:

```
var myList = (from l in dataContext.Videos
where results.Contains(l.ID)
select l).ToList(); //grab data and resolve to list or array

var orderedByIDList = from k in results
join l in myList
on k equals l.Id
select l; //result type IEnumerable<Video>
```

Comment: Don't think you can join dataContext table with local collection

Comment: I just tried it and it works in Entity Framework, not in Linq to SQL. However it appears to select the whole table and join locally which is not that good.

Comment: You need 'on k equals l.Id'.  It doesn't work the other way round.

Comment: @Phil, thanks again. With the a decent SQL execution path, shouldn't a full table join on an integer index (yeah 'index' assumption) be just as fast?

Comment: @InfinitePossiblities: Not sure what you mean, just as fast as what?

Comment: @Phil you talked about a whole table join, shouldn't the performance downside to that be completely negligible if any assuming the join is on equality of an indexed column since the SQL execution path will actually perform the `where` clause first

Comment: @InfinitePossiblities No, your original join is translated into 'select * from table'.  The join is done after the whole table is retrieved into memory locally.  Your second version is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my alternative attempt (probably not as fast as a join), which retrieves the minimum set of rows and then orders the data locally.

```
var results = new List<int>{ 9, 2, 3, 6, 8 };

// record the original order
var results2 = results.Select ((r, index) => new {r, index});

// get results and convert to list
var videos = dataContext.Videos.Where(v => results.Contains(v.Id)).ToList();

// order according to results order
var ordered = videos.Select (v => 
    new {v, results2.Single (r => r.r == v.Id).index})
    .OrderBy (v => v.index).Select (v => v.v)
```